# Set default stage with Capistrano 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano

Is there a way to set a default stage in Capistrano 3?

I've tried putting `set :stage, :production` inside deploy.rb but that didn't work, it gives the error:

```
Stage not set, please call something such as `cap production deploy`,
where production is a stage you have defined
```

I only have one stage right now so I want to be able to just run `cap deploy` and have it execute on the default.

Comment: I was going to add same question today, but I thought I can't find some basic, obvious option, unfortunately it seems it's not so obvious (really strange) and there's almost no documentation regarding v3.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Capistrano v3 is somewhat of a wrapper around Rake, so you need to realize that what's really happening is that a `production` task is getting run first, followed by a `deploy` task.

If you debug it a little, you'll find that `deploy.rb` doesn't get loaded when you don't type in a stage. This is because the stage's task is where `deploy.rb` gets loaded: Looking at [`lib/setup.rb`](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/blob/master/lib/capistrano/setup.rb), a task is defined for each stage. When run, the stage's task sets `:stage`, loads up the capistrano defaults, and then finally loads your `deploy.rb` file.

So, an easy trick would be to tell Capistrano to invoke the stage task every time you run `cap` by adding this to the end of your `Capfile` (**not** your `deploy.rb`):

```
Rake::Task[:production].invoke
```

or, using the `invoke` method from Capistrano's DSL:

```
invoke :production
```

This may have some unintended consequences if you actually do use multiple stages, but if you only ever use the `production` stage, it should work fine.

Another easy solution could be a simple shell alias, such as `alias cap='cap production'`, but it might not work great if you have multiple projects with different stage names.

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful. I've never used Rake before but thinking it may be helpful to read the Rake docs to better understand capistrano 3.

Answer (score 5):

After I `cd` into the RAILS Root directory, issuing the command:

`cap development deploy`

seems to work. Earlier I was in the app/models folder and issuing the command came back with this error:

`Stage not set, please call something such as cap production deploy, where production is a stage you have defined.`

Answer (score 4):

The old solution works for me in Capistrano 3:

```
cap --version
#=> Capistrano Version: 3.3.5 (Rake Version: 10.4.2)
```

At the very top of the `Capfile` after these lines

```
# Load DSL and Setup Up Stages
require 'capistrano/setup'
```

add:

```
set :stage, :production
```

and then run you task as usual without the stage specified:

```
cap foo:bar
```

Comment: what did you mean by `cap foo:bar` ?

Comment: It is just an example name of a task. For example of example (!) it could be `cap deploy:migrate` or `cap cache:clear`.

Answer (score 1):

New answer for capistrano 3.6+:
It's better to use `invoke :production unless Rake.application.options.show_tasks` to avoid the warning which you would otherwise get with `cap -T`

Comment: Had to add this to the end of the Capfile not near the start.

Answer (score -1):

You can add the following line to your deploy.rb, which will prevent Capistrano from expecting a stage:

```
set :stages, ["production"]
```