# Unable to activate capistrano-rails-1.2.3 , conflicts with capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I have the following problem at the next tutorial on Deploy Ruby On Rails on
Ubuntu 16.04: https://gorails.com/deploy/ubuntu/16.04

The issue appears to be with capistrano.

```
nicoara@ubuntu:~/deploy_test$ cap install STAGES=production
/home/nicoara/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:2112:in `raise_if_conflicts': Unable to activate capistrano-rails-1.2.3, because capistrano-2.15.9 conflicts with capistrano (~> 3.1) (Gem::ConflictError)
           from /home/nicoara/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1280:in `activate'
           from /home/nicoara/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems.rb:198:in `rescue in try_activate'
           from /home/nicoara/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems.rb:195:in `try_activate'

...
```

my gemfile has:

```
   group :development do
   gem 'capistrano', '~> 3.7', '>= 3.7.1'
   gem 'capistrano-rails', '~> 1.2'
   gem 'capistrano-passenger', '~> 0.2.0'
   gem 'capistrano-rbenv', '~> 2.1'
```

my capfile has:

```
   # Capfile
   require 'capistrano/rails'
   require 'capistrano/passenger'

   # If you are using rbenv add these lines:
   require 'capistrano/rbenv'
   set :rbenv_type, :user
   set :rbenv_ruby, '2.4.0'
```

what to do?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message says that:

> because **capistrano-2.15.9** conflicts

So apparently Capistrano 2.15.9 is being executed, even though your intention as described by your Gemfile is to use capistrano 3.7.

Use `bundle exec cap` to ensure that you are running the version of Capistrano that is specified in the Gemfile.

Comment: Thanks for answering. 
nicoara@ubuntu:~/deploy_test$ bundle exec cap
(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `stages' for Capistrano::DSL:Module
/home/nicoara/deploy_test/Capfile:2:in `require'
/home/nicoara/deploy_test/Capfile:2:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

Seems to be a problem with the fact that Capfile starts with:
# Capfile
require "capistrano/rails"
require "capistrano/passenger"

Comment: Your Capfile should not start with those lines. The tutorial says to *add* those lines to the Capfile. The original contents of the Capfile should not be removed. Make sure these things are at the top: https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/blob/7ba6e446ff4f517814d8e5a79710aa122a8b9064/lib/capistrano/templates/Capfile

Comment: now shows : "LoadError: cannot load such file -- capistrano/passenger"
. I see that Passenger does not appear in "gem list".

Comment: Sorry, based on what you've posted and if you are using `bundle exec`, I don't see how such an error is possible. I'm out of ideas. Good luck!

Comment: sorry, was missing gem 'capistrano-passenger', '~> 0.2.0' in gemfile somehow. now "bundle exec cap" shows "Stage not set, please call something such as `cap production deploy`" . Now "cap production deploy" or "cap install STAGES=production" both show " `require': cannot load such file -- capistrano/setup (LoadError)
", the first line in Capfile. What to do? Thanks

Comment: @NicoaraTalpes check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27929637/1682542

Comment: thanks, it did not work. i added the new question here for points: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43790085/cannot-load-such-file-capistrano-setup-loaderror