# cannot load such file -- capistrano/setup (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano, passenger

I am following https://gorails.com/deploy/ubuntu/16.04

Initially i have one version of capistrano 3.8.1 and my problem initially is:

```
nicoara@ubuntu:~/deploy_test$ cap install STAGES=production
  /home/nicoara/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- capistrano/cli (LoadError)
```

i solve this with "gem install rvm-capistrano" which installs another version of capistrano as well, 2.15.6, and now the error is:

```
nicoara@ubuntu:~/deploy_test$ cap install STAGES=production:
`require': cannot load such file -- capistrano/setup (LoadError)
```

which is unsolvable to me at this point.

Comment: Did you run `bundle install` after adding Capistrano to your Gemfile? It looks like that is missing from the gorails.com steps.

Comment: yes, already had done this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the comment states, there are a few steps to follow:

1. Make sure all `capistrano/*` gems are listed in your Gemfile.
2. Run `bundle install` to install them.
3. Make sure they're spelled correctly in your Capfile (I've messed that up more than once!).
4. Prepend `cap` commands with `bundle exec` to be extra safe, i.e. `STAGES=production bundle exec cap install`.

Comment: thanks, that changed the error! now, although i have ruby 2.4.0 on both my development machine and the server, when i do "bundle exec cap production deploy
" at step 10 i get the error:
... 00:13 bundler:install
 $HOME/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle install --path /home/deploy/deploy_test1/shared/bundle --without development test --deployment --q … 
      01 rbenv: bundle: command not found
      01 The `bundle' command exists in these Ruby versions:
      01   2.4.0

Comment: posted my follow up question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43878840/cap-deploy-rbenv-bundle-command-not-found