# cap deploy + rbenv: bundle: command not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, capistrano, capistrano3

I am following https://gorails.com/deploy/ubuntu/16.04

I am running : "bundle exec cap production deploy"
and getting the following error:

```
    ✔ 10 deploy@107.170.84.18 0.289s
00:21 bundler:install
      01 $HOME/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle install --path /home/deploy/deploy_test1/shared/bundle --without development test --deployment --q…
      01 rbenv: bundle: command not found
      01
      01 The `bundle' command exists in these Ruby versions:
      01   2.4.0
      01
(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as deploy@107.170.84.18: bundle exit status: 127
bundle stdout: Nothing written
bundle stderr: rbenv: bundle: command not found

The `bundle' command exists in these Ruby versions:
  2.4.0

SSHKit::Command::Failed: bundle exit status: 127
bundle stdout: Nothing written
bundle stderr: rbenv: bundle: command not found

The `bundle' command exists in these Ruby versions:
  2.4.0

Tasks: TOP => deploy:updated => bundler:install
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
The deploy has failed with an error: Exception while executing as deploy@107.170.84.18: bundle exit status: 127
bundle stdout: Nothing written
bundle stderr: rbenv: bundle: command not found

The `bundle' command exists in these Ruby versions:
  2.4.0


** DEPLOY FAILED
** Refer to log/capistrano.log for details. Here are the last 20 lines:


 DEBUG [3de26178] Command: ( export RBENV_ROOT="$HOME/.rbenv" RBENV_VERSION="2.3.1" ; /usr/bin/env ln -s /home/deploy/deploy_test1/shared/public/assets /home/deploy/deploy_test1/releases/20170509194018/public/assets )

  INFO [3de26178] Finished in 0.289 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).

 DEBUG [25920183] Running if test ! -d /home/deploy/deploy_test1/releases/20170509194018; then echo "Directory does not exist '/home/deploy/deploy_test1/releases/20170509194018'" 1>&2; false; fi as deploy@107.170.84.18

 DEBUG [25920183] Command: if test ! -d /home/deploy/deploy_test1/releases/20170509194018; then echo "Directory does not exist '/home/deploy/deploy_test1/releases/20170509194018'" 1>&2; false; fi

 DEBUG [25920183] Finished in 0.291 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).

 DEBUG [7b4c3ff7] Running $HOME/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle check --path /home/deploy/deploy_test1/shared/bundle as deploy@107.170.84.18

 DEBUG [7b4c3ff7] Command: cd /home/deploy/deploy_test1/releases/20170509194018 && ( export RBENV_ROOT="$HOME/.rbenv" RBENV_VERSION="2.3.1" ; $HOME/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle check --path /home/deploy/deploy_test1/shared/bundle )

 DEBUG [7b4c3ff7]   rbenv: bundle: command not found

 DEBUG [7b4c3ff7]   

The `bundle' command exists in these Ruby versions:

 DEBUG [7b4c3ff7]     2.4.0

 DEBUG [7b4c3ff7]   

 DEBUG [7b4c3ff7] Finished in 0.399 seconds with exit status 127 (failed).

  INFO [3bbf2dfd] Running $HOME/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle install --path /home/deploy/deploy_test1/shared/bundle --without development test --deployment --quiet as deploy@107.170.84.18

 DEBUG [3bbf2dfd] Command: cd /home/deploy/deploy_test1/releases/20170509194018 && ( export RBENV_ROOT="$HOME/.rbenv" RBENV_VERSION="2.3.1" ; $HOME/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle install --path /home/deploy/deploy_test1/shared/bundle --without development test --deployment --quiet )

 DEBUG [3bbf2dfd]   rbenv: bundle: command not found

 DEBUG [3bbf2dfd]   

The `bundle' command exists in these Ruby versions:

 DEBUG [3bbf2dfd]     2.4.0

 DEBUG [3bbf2dfd]
```

"gem list" shows : bundler (1.14.6) on both machines, as well as ruby 2.4.0 on both my production machine as well as the server. 
How to proceed?

I am posting my Capfile:

```
# Load DSL and set up stages
require "capistrano/setup"

# Include default deployment tasks
require "capistrano/deploy"

# Load the SCM plugin appropriate to your project:
#
# require "capistrano/scm/hg"
# install_plugin Capistrano::SCM::Hg
# or
# require "capistrano/scm/svn"
# install_plugin Capistrano::SCM::Svn
# or
require "capistrano/scm/git"
install_plugin Capistrano::SCM::Git

# If you are using rbenv add these lines:
require 'capistrano/rbenv'
set :rbenv_type, :user
set :rbenv_ruby, '2.3.1'

require 'capistrano/bundler'
require 'capistrano/rails'
require 'capistrano/passenger'

# Load custom tasks from `lib/capistrano/tasks` if you have any defined
Dir.glob("lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake").each { |r| import r }
```

my deploy.rb:

```
# config valid only for current version of Capistrano
lock "3.8.1"

set :application, "deploy_test1"
set :repo_url, "git@bitbucket.org:confidentialname/deploy_test1.git"

set :deploy_to, '/home/deploy/deploy_test1'

#append :linked_files, "config/database.yml", "config/secrets.yml"
append :linked_dirs, "log", "tmp/pids", "tmp/cache", "tmp/sockets", "vendor/bundle", "public/system", "public/uploads"
```

Comment: Do you have bundler installed on the machine you are deploying to?

Comment: yes, running "bundler -v" shows Bundler version 1.14.6 on both machines.

Comment: Could you post your capfile and deploy.rb? Anonymized appropriately.

Comment: @will_in_wi added the corresponding files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like `rbenv` is set to run Ruby 2.3.1. Several places in the log you have `RBENV_VERSION="2.3.1"`. According to [the rbenv documentation](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#installing-ruby-gems), you can find out how that was set with `rbenv version`. If you want to test Ruby 2.4.0, you'll need to point to that version. Alternatively, if you really mean to run on 2.3.1, you'll need to install bundler.

Comment: i am not sure how to point to that newer version. on both machines:  ruby -v shows: ruby 2.4.0p0 (2016-12-24 revision 57164) [x86_64-linux] and  rbenv -v shows: rbenv 1.1.0-2-g4f8925a. going locally on ~./rbenv/versions/ shows just 2.4.0 . where did i set RBENV_VERSION="2.3.1" ? thanks

Comment: In your Capfile, you have the line set :rbenv_ruby, '2.3.1'. change that to the version you want.

Comment: @will_in_wi this fixed it, but right afterwards there was a new bug. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44008509/rake-exit-status-139. do you know an easier way to connect a database to a rails app than this tutorial? thanks