# rake exit status: 139

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rbenv, capistrano3

I am following https://gorails.com/deploy/ubuntu/16.04

I am running : "bundle exec cap production deploy" and getting the following error:

```
         01 $HOME/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle install --path /home/deploy/deploy_test1/shared/bundle --without development test --deployment --q…
        ✔ 01 deploy@107.170.84.18 3.251s
    00:21 deploy:assets:precompile
          01 $HOME/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle exec rake assets:precompile
          01 /home/deploy/deploy_test1/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:121: w…
          01 /home/deploy/deploy_test1/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:121: w…
          01 bash: line 1: 23934 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) $HOME/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle exec rake assets:precompile
    (Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
    cap aborted!
    SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as deploy@107.170.84.18: rake exit status: 139
    rake stdout: Nothing written
    rake stderr: /home/deploy/deploy_test1/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:121: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
    /home/deploy/deploy_test1/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:121: warning: constant ::Bignum is deprecated
    bash: line 1: 23934 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) $HOME/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle exec rake assets:precompile

    SSHKit::Command::Failed: rake exit status: 139
    rake stdout: Nothing written
    rake stderr: /home/deploy/deploy_test1/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:121: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
    /home/deploy/deploy_test1/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:121: warning: constant ::Bignum is deprecated
    bash: line 1: 23934 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) $HOME/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle exec rake assets:precompile

    Tasks: TOP => deploy:assets:precompile
    (See full trace by running task with --trace)
    The deploy has failed with an error: Exception while executing as deploy@107.170.84.18: rake exit status: 139
    rake stdout: Nothing written
    rake stderr: /home/deploy/deploy_test1/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:121: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
    /home/deploy/deploy_test1/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:121: warning: constant ::Bignum is deprecated
    bash: line 1: 23934 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) $HOME/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle exec rake assets:precompile
......
......
/home/deploy/deploy_test1/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
/home/deploy/deploy_test1/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
/home/deploy/deploy_test1/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
/home/deploy/deploy_test1/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:138:in `local_cache_key'
/home/deploy/deploy_test1/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:74:in `middleware'
/home/deploy/deploy_test1/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/application/bootstrap.rb:79:in `block in <module:Bootstrap>'
/home/deploy/deploy_test1/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/home/deploy/deploy_test1/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/home/deploy/deploy_test1/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/home/deploy/deploy_test1/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/home/deploy/deploy_test1/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
/home/deploy/deploy_test1/releases/20170516175610/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/home/deploy/deploy_test1/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require'
/home/deploy/deploy_test1/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require_environment!'
/home/deploy/deploy_test1/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/application.rb:457:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
/home/deploy/deploy_test1/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:62:in `block (2 levels) in define'
/home/deploy/deploy_test1/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/bin/bundle:22:in `load'
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/bin/bundle:22:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)


** DEPLOY FAILED
** Refer to log/capistrano.log for details. Here are the last 20 lines:


/home/deploy/deploy_test1/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'

/home/deploy/deploy_test1/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'

/home/deploy/deploy_test1/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:138:in `local_cache_key'

/home/deploy/deploy_test1/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:74:in `middleware'

/home/deploy/deploy_test1/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/application/bootstrap.rb:79:in `block in <module:Bootstrap>'

/home/deploy/deploy_test1/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'

/home/deploy/deploy_test1/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'

/home/deploy/deploy_test1/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'

/home/deploy/deploy_test1/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'

/home/deploy/deploy_test1/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'

/home/deploy/deploy_test1/releases/20170516175610/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'

/home/deploy/deploy_test1/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require'

/home/deploy/deploy_test1/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require_environment!'

/home/deploy/deploy_test1/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/application.rb:457:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'

/home/deploy/deploy_test1/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:62:in `block (2 levels) in define'

/home/deploy/deploy_test1/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'

/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/bin/bundle:22:in `load'

/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/bin/bundle:22:in `<main>'

Tasks: TOP => environment

(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

my Capfile is the one from here with rbenv 2.4.0:
[cap deploy + rbenv: bundle: command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43878840/cap-deploy-rbenv-bundle-command-not-found?noredirect=1#comment74889497_43878840)

Comment: You have a SEGFAULT (which means, your ruby process died, often because of incompatible C-extensions). In addition to that, you are using Rails 4.2.4 with Ruby 2.4. This won't work. The first version of Rails 4.2 to be compatible with Ruby 2.4 is Rails 4.2.8.

Comment: If you need to use Rails `4.2.4`, then use Ruby `2.3.x` (ideally `2.3.4`). If you need to use Rails `4.2.x`, and want to use Ruby `2.4.x`, then use Rails `4.2.8` (and ideally Ruby `2.4.1`). Or if you have no good reason to restrict the versions (e.g. if this is a new project), then just go for the latest versions of both: Rails `5.1.1` and Ruby `2.4.1`.

Comment: For a little bit of context here, see: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2017/2/21/Rails-4-2-8-has-been-released/

Comment: @HolgerJust I specified in my Gemfile "gem 'rails', '5.1.1'", and my ruby is 2.4.0p0 . now error is:
 01 $HOME/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle exec rake assets:precompile
      01 /home/deploy/deploy_test1/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:121: warning: constant ::Fixnum …
      01 rake aborted!
      01 SystemStackError: stack level too deep
      01 /home/deploy/deploy_test1/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:124:in `block (2 levels) in <cla…

Comment: @TomLord replied above . thanks

Comment: @NicoaraTalpes ".../ruby/<<2.4.0>>/gems/acti‌​vesupport-<<4.2.4>>/lib/..." -- You're *still* using Rails `4.2.4`, and why are you not using ruby `2.4.1`?

Comment: @TomLord know i have ruby 2.4.1 on both local and server. but somehow it keeps installing on the server at /home/deploy/deploy_test1/shared/bundle/ruby the version 2.4.0 and keeps repeating the same error. how do i tell it not to install this version? my Capfile has "set :rbenv_ruby, '2.4.1'". Thanks

Comment: @HolgerJust I have updated the problem with a comment. Thanks

Comment: I don't know, @NicoaraTalpes. Without knowing *exactly* what you are doing to cause this behaviour, and without a reproducible example, I can only guess. My best guess at this point is that you are typing `git commit`, but not `git push` - and so therefore are deploying the wrong version.